# Cannot replace existing files in a folder in Yosemite

Tags: finder, macos

I am having a problem with the Finder, Copy and Replace to be exact, and I was hoping someone could help me troubleshoot. I am have been on Yosemite for one week and just noticed the issue a couple of days ago.

**The issue:**
When I copy a file into a folder where another file with the same name exists, nothing happens.  I am able to copy files that do not exist in a folder without issues.

**What I think is happening:**
I believe the Finder does try to trigger whatever service is responsible for loading up the Copy and Replace dialog box because if I try to restart the computer after I have attempted replace an existing file I get an error message saying "The Finder can't quit because some operations are still in progress."

At the point, the only way to be able to restart the computer is to Force Quit the Finder.  Reloading the Finder about 4-5 times also fixes this issue and I am able to replace existing files.

**What I've tried"**
I went into Activity Monitor to see if I could figure out which process was responsible for copying and I narrowed it down to DesktopServicesHelper.  I was hoping that if I could replace it with a know working copy, the issue would be resolved.  I copied that file from my Macbook but the issue did not get resolved.

I also reinstalled Yosemite on top of my existing Yosemite installation and the problem still persists.  Lastly, I've run Disk Utility and repaired permissions a whole lot of times too.

Anyone know what else I could try?